# get ConversationalRetrievalChain from curl request?

Tags: python, curl, langchain, large-language-model

Let's assume I have a llm model which runs on an AWS ec2 instance.
I have the URL and can send it questions via

```
payload = {
      "model": "mistralai/Mistral-7B-v0.1",
      "prompt": "My favourite condiment is",
      "max_tokens": 25
      }

data = json.dumps(payload, ensure_ascii=False)
response = requests.post(url=url, data=data)
```

Is there a way to get a langchain ConversationalRetrievalChain out of this?
When i have an endpoint from sagemaker, i can use

```
llm = SagemakerEndpoint(ENDPOINT_INFOS_GO_HERE)
chain = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(llm=llm, retriever=db.as_retriever())  # <-- also, I have some db hooked up
```

But in this case i just have an url.

Comment: you can create wrapper for ConversationalRetrievalChain and expose that as endpoint

Comment: and how would i be doing that?